# Multiply two input field and result in the third field which changes when either of the input field changed with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, multiplication

I need to Multiply two user Input Fields and show the results in the third field. The Result field must change when either of the User Input fields are changed.

```
<input type="number" name="rate" id="rate" />
<input type="number" name="box" id="box" />
```

The result should be in a third field which changes when either of the two above fields is changed. This totally depends on the user input

```
<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" readonly />
```

I need to do this Multiplication with Jquery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this : bind `change` event listener for `rate` and `box` input box and inside it multiply the values to put it in `amount` input.

```
$('#rate, #box').change(function(){
    var rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val()) || 0;
    var box = parseFloat($('#box').val()) || 0;

    $('#amount').val(rate * box);    
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2L95x1u9/)**

You can use `keyup` event to calculate `amount` as soon as you enter other fields

```
$('#rate, #box').keyup(function(){
    var rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val()) || 0;
    var box = parseFloat($('#box').val()) || 0;

    $('#amount').val(rate * box);    
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2L95x1u9/1/)**

Comment: I have jquery-1.11.1. It does not reflect
*Note: I'm executing this code in the LOCALHOST*

Comment: for jquery 1.11, it is working for me see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2L95x1u9/2/). There could be some error, please check browser console. Please check if your jquery lib path is correct.

Comment: yes, it will work on any enviroment. This script run on browser i.e. on client side.

Comment: It doesnt work brother. Im using the code in the localhost with XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

Try this : bind `input` event listener `on` rate and box input box and inside it multiply the values to put it in amount input.

The `input` event only fires when the value of the input has changed whereas `change` only fires once the field has lost focus. input fires immediately

```js
$('#rate, #box').on('input',function(){
    var rate = parseFloat($('#rate').val()) || 0;
    var box = parseFloat($('#box').val()) || 0;

    $('#amount').val(rate * box);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="rate" id="rate" value=""/>
<input type="number" name="box" id="box" value=""/>
<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" readonly />
```

Comment: I have jquery-1.11.1 in my LOCALHOST and already linked it to the page.

Comment: ya bro it will work fine with that version of jquery too

Comment: It doesnt work for me. I've tried different browsers too bro.

Comment: see console what error you are getting because for me it is working fine bro

Comment: I forgot to mention. These input fields are in a Form. Does this work now? And i dowloaded th jQuery from jQuery.com

Comment: ya that should not be a problem.

Comment: I do not get any error messages in the console except that it does not show the result. Whee do I download the jQuery file from?

Comment: just use this cdn and see <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script>
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   console.log('jquery is not working');
}else{
    console.log('jquery is working');
}
</script>

but this code immediate after the jquery cdn link and see what message you are getting

Comment: No errors in the console. Just a blank page. Im using it in localhost using XAMPP

Comment: Thank you brother. Works now. I had a huge form. I placed the script just before the Amount box and it works fine. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 cents on the above scenario -
http://jsfiddle.net/ak9ejpne/3/

My aim was to keep the code thin & clean and with some MVC flavor.

```
function Operand(a,b){
  this.a = parseInt(a);
  this.b = b;
  this.c = (this.a)*(this.b);

  this.set = function(key,edit){
    this[key] = edit;
    this.c = (this.a)*(this.b);  
  };
  return this;
}
```

Do let me know if it is a useful approach for you :)

Answer (score 0):

## You can Try It.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#txtOne,#txtTwo").on("change keyup", function(e){  
      var txtOne = parseFloat($("#txtOne").val()); 
      var txtTwo = parseFloat($("#txtTwo").val()); 
      var result = txtOne * txtTwo ; 
      if (!isNaN(result)) { 
          $("#txtAmount").val(result); 
       }  
    }); 
 </script>
```